# Nested ng-repeat failing when property values in being used

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use the below data in my code:

```
$scope.masterData = {"list": {
  "PPP0001188": ["01","02","03"],
  "PPP0001189": ["01","02","03"]
 }}
```

I want to display the same as:

PPP0001188: 01  02  03

The html I am using is as follows:

```
            <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in masterData.list">
                <div>
                    <span>{{key}}</span>
                    <ul class="storeIdList">
                        <li ng-repeat = "store in {{val}}">
                            <button class="btn btn-default siteBtns">{{store}}</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The inner ng-repeat loop is failing although if I populate {{val}}, it returns me an array. Can anyone suggest the right syntax???

Answer (score 3):

Just replace

```
<li ng-repeat = "store in {{val}}">
```

by

```
<li ng-repeat = "store in val">
```

Comment: Thanks. I worked it myself but the answer is exactly correct. :)

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark it as answer to show that this solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

second ng-repeat should look like this:

```
<li ng-repeat ="store in val">
```

here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JSl0p80JkSBh7LzEmuDk?p=preview)